# Remove Unchecked and Unwanted text results from my submission form with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am facing an issue where my checkboxes seem irrelevant. When processing my form text shows up for unchecked boxes. I want the end result to only show the ticked boxes. There is too much information showing in my results.

Or would it be easier to ditch checkboxes and use a drop list, if so how would I be able to assign the price to each drop box item? Checkboxes was my alternative to this idea and I seem to still be having trouble

Thanks in advance

Here is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Movie Ticket Prices</title>
<!-- script src="movie.js" type="text/javascript"></script -->
<script src="movie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1">

<div> Choose a movie: 
<select name="movie" id="movie">
 <option value="Never say never">Never say never</option>
 <option value="Hop">Hop</option>
 <option value="Rio">Rio</option>
</select>
</div>

<div> Choose a Day: 
<select name="day" id="day">
 <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
 <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
 <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
</select>
</div>

<div>
 Name: <input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox" value="" />
</div>

<div>
 <label> <input type="checkbox" id="CAtickets" value="10" checked />Child tickets: </label>
 How many: <input type="text" id="CA" value="0" size="3" />
 <br>
 <label> <input type="checkbox" id="SAtickets" value="20" checked />Adult tickets: </label>
 How many: <input type="text" id="SA" value="0" size="3" />
 <br>
 <label> <input type="checkbox" id="SPtickets" value="18" checked />Concession tickets: </label>
 How many: <input type="text" id="SP" value="0" size="3" />
 <br>
 <label> <input type="checkbox" id="FAtickets" value="30" checked />First Class Adult tickets: </label>
 How many: <input type="text" id="FA" value="0" size="3" />
 <br>
 <label> <input type="checkbox" id="FCtickets" value="20" checked />First Class Child tickets: </label>
 How many: <input type="text" id="FC" value="0" size="3" />
 <br>
 <label> <input type="checkbox" id="B1tickets" value="20" checked />Beanbag 1 Person tickets: </label>
 How many: <input type="text" id="B1" value="0" size="3" />
 <br>
 <label> <input type="checkbox" id="B2tickets" value="25" checked />Beanbag 2 person tickets: </label>
 How many: <input type="text" id="B2" value="0" size="3" />
 <br>
 <label> <input type="checkbox" id="B3tickets" value="30" checked />Beanbag 3 person tickets: </label>
 How many: <input type="text" id="B3" value="0" size="3" />
 <br>


 <p><input type="button" value="Purchase" onclick="printPrice()" />
</div>

</form>

<div id="inserts"> </div>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
function printPrice() {
  var movie = document.getElementById("movie").value;
  var day = document.getElementById("day").value;
  var name = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
  var CA = document.getElementById("CA").value * 1;
  var SA = document.getElementById("SP").value * 1;
  var SP = document.getElementById("SP").value * 1;
  var FA = document.getElementById("FA").value * 1;
  var FC = document.getElementById("FC").value * 1;
  var B1 = document.getElementById("B1").value * 1;
  var B2 = document.getElementById("B2").value * 1;
  var B3 = document.getElementById("B3").value * 1;
  var total = 0;
  var sentence = "";
  var price = document.getElementById('CAtickets').value * CA;

  sentence += name + "<br>purchased "+CA+" Child ticket(s) to \"";
   sentence += day +'<br>';
  sentence += movie + "\" for $";
  sentence += price;
  total += price;

  price = document.getElementById('SAtickets').value * SA;
  sentence += "<br>and "+SA+" Adult ticket(s) to \"";
  sentence += day +'<br>';
  sentence += movie + "\" for $";
  sentence += price +'<br>';
  total += price;

  price = document.getElementById('SPtickets').value * SP;
  sentence += "<br>and "+SP+" Concession ticket(s) to \"";
  sentence += day +'<br>';
  sentence += movie + "\" for $";
  sentence += price +'<br>';
  total += price;

  price = document.getElementById('FAtickets').value * FA;
  sentence += "<br>and "+FA+" First Class Adult ticket(s) to \"";
  sentence += day +'<br>';
  sentence += movie + "\" for $";
  sentence += price +'<br>';
  total += price;

price = document.getElementById('FCtickets').value * FC;
  sentence += "<br>and "+FC+" First Class Child ticket(s) to \"";
  sentence += day +'<br>';
  sentence += movie + "\" for $";
  sentence += price +'<br>';
  total += price;

price = document.getElementById('B1tickets').value * B1;
  sentence += "<br>and "+B1+" Beanbag 1 to \"";
  sentence += day +'<br>';
  sentence += movie + "\" for $";
  sentence += price +'<br>';
  total += price;

price = document.getElementById('B2tickets').value * B2;
  sentence += "<br>and "+B2+" Beanbag 2 to \"";
  sentence += day +'<br>';
  sentence += movie + "\" for $";
  sentence += price +'<br>';
  total += price;

  price = document.getElementById('B3tickets').value * B3;
  sentence += "<br>and "+B3+" Beanbag 3 to \"";
  sentence += day +'<br>';
  sentence += movie + "\" for $";
  sentence += price +'<br>';
  total += price;


  sentence += "<br>";
  sentence += 'Total cost: $'+total;
  document.getElementById("inserts").innerHTML=sentence;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

Ok you need to restrucutre your html somewhat, and also add event listeners to your checkboxes to show/hide content related to them. I've created a fiddle which I believe reproduces desired behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/tfx05wdd/

---

You are adding text to the `sentence` string regardless of if the checkbox is checked or not. To check wheter a checkbox is checked use this:

```
document.getElementById('checkboxId').checked
```

In your case it might look something like this:

```
if(document.getElementById('B3tickets').checked) {
    var price = document.getElementById('B3tickets').value * B3;
    sentence += "<br>and "+B3+" Beanbag 3 to \"";
    sentence += day +'<br>';
    sentence += movie + "\" for $";
    sentence += price +'<br>';
    total += price;
}
```

Comment: I left the B3 box unchecked and it still shows text.
Is that the only way to get sentence to display only when used?

Comment: Im not sure what you're asking here, do you want no text at all to be displayed if one of the boxes are unchecked?

Comment: I just want text to be shown for the boxes ticked. The ones unticked I want them to remain hidden. Sorry for the confusion, thanks

Comment: Ok I've updated the answer, check the fiddle. Hopefully this will help solve your problem